# JSON output from Tridion Java DXA 1.7

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.7

I have below requirement in my project using Java DXA 1.7, I am new to DXA.
Can someone provide me which Component Template and Page Template should I use for my requirement?

Also how can I achieve my JSON output in my custom controller?

Schema Name: Custom Content

Fields in Schema:

- `title` - Text Field
- `contentBody` - RichText Box
- `footerContent` - Rich Text Box

When I request through http://mydomain.com/CustomController/MyPageName

My Desired Output should be as below JSON format:

```
{
    "title":"Some Title",
    "contentBody":"Some RichText Content",
    "footerContent: "Again Some RichText Content"
}
```

Comment: So, if you request some Page, you want to return JSON representing the content of a Component on that Page? What if there are multiple Components on the Page?

Comment: Rick - I need the content in an array object.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is somewhat similar to this: [How to render plain JSON (without any additional tag) data in DXA 1.5 java?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18775/how-to-render-plain-json-without-any-additional-tag-data-in-dxa-1-5-java)

However, what you want seems to be more in line with what DXA is designed for. Nevertheless, you will need to use a custom Page Controller which returns the JSON you want.

The underlying data can be obtained from the Page Model: `pageModel.getRegions().get(“Main”).getEntities()`. This will return a set of Entity Models of a type which you defined (and registered).

You could use a regular Strongly Typed Entity Model, which uses individual properties for each field. Alternatively, you can use a special semantic mapping where all CM fields are mapped to a single property of type `Map<String,String>`. If you serialize such property to JSON, it will yield the output you’re looking for.

The DXA Framework comes with a predefined Entity Model type that uses this “all CM fields to single property” mapping: class [`Configuration`](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/blob/master/dxa-framework/dxa-common-api/src/main/java/com/sdl/webapp/common/api/model/entity/Configuration.java). You can use this class instead of defining your own Entity Model.

Comment: Rick - Can I get example code for the custom page controller?