# Get content as JSON by sending Accept header

Tags: dxa

As explained in [How to render plain JSON (without any additional tag) data in DXA 1.5 java?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18775/how-to-render-plain-json-without-any-additional-tag-data-in-dxa-1-5-java), it is possible to retrieve the contents of a page as JSON by adding ?format=json to the URL. I've tried that in DXA 2, and it still works fine.

However, it is also claimed that you can achieve the same result by sending an Accept header with value 'application/json'. This does not work for me. Do I need to send another header as well? Or was this feature removed in DXA 2?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it should be possible to get JSON format by specifying an HTTP `Accept` header with value `application/json`

See method `DataFormatters.GetFormat` in https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Sdl.Web.Mvc/Formats/DataFormatters.cs

Admittedly, the logic to select a data formatter based on `Accept` header is quite convoluted (it can use some refactoring!) and might be defective as a result.

Comment: Convoluted is an understatement if you ask me.. Anyway, as a monkey tester I can tell you it doesn't work :)

Comment: I miss the simple logic of: if acceptHeader == application/json then return application/json indeed. Might be good to log a ticket for this?

Comment: Yes, by all means, report an [Issue in GitHub](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/issues).